# displaying pics in django tempaltes unevenly

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I am new to Django and I have a html template which have uneven pics but i have no idea how to do the for in my html file while getting the pics from DB. can someone please help me?

this is the thing that I want?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K8NI.jpg)

I have no idea for this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: haven't started to be able to provide code